# The TargetControlID of 'CalendarExtender1' is not valid. A control with ID 'text1' could not be found

Tags: c#

I have created the Textbox and using CalendarExtener dynamically. I am getting the error"The TargetControlID of 'CalendarExtender1' is not valid. A control with ID 'text1' could not be found."

The below is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "text1";
        AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender publishdate = new AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender();
        publishdate.ID = "CalendarExtender1";
        publishdate.TargetControlID = tb.ID;
        Panel1.Controls.Add(publishdate);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't added the `TextBox` to the page's control collection.

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
Panel1.Controls.Add(publishdate);
```

Can i ask why you want to create it dynamically? That will make things much more difficult than adding declaratively and might cause issues with events or ViewState.